# Iptables. Выходить в интернет через разные внешние ip

Tags: linux, маршрутизация, iptables

Ситуация:
У меня на шлюзе linux на одном интерфейсе eth0 несколько внешних ip:
156.x.x.12
156.x.x.13

Через 156.x.x.12 все выходят в интернет + проброшены порты для почты.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.16.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 156.x.x.12 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.16.0.2:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 156.x.x.12 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.16.0.2:443
```

Все хорошо, у почтового сервера все ок, белый ip - 156.x.x.12. У клиентов 10.16.0.0/24 тоже белый ip 156.x.x.12

Вопрос: как мне сделать чтобы у клиента 10.16.0.3 был внешний ip 156.x.x.13? Ну т.е. чтобы он выходил через ip 156.x.x.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй правило SNAT для него перед правилом MASQUERDE. Если доп ип адреса в роутинге провайдера, то заработает. Если в link скоупе, то добавь их алиасами на интерфейс.